# What is `String("a")` type

Tags: scala

I tried the following code below:

```
scala> // Scala 2.13.8

scala> val a = "a"
val a: String = a

scala> val a: "a" = "a"
val a: "a" = a

scala> final val a = "a"
val a: String("a") = a
```

I know that `String` is normal type and `"a"` is a literal type.

What is `String("a")`?

Comment: Is probably another way the REPL shows the literal type `"a"`

Comment: I'd call it a bug, actually, that the REPL shows the type using syntax that isn't real syntax.